# User Activity - SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, data-analysis, user-activity

I need some help in writing an SQL query

Here are the data:
Application usage data is kept in the following table:
**Table sessions: Id, userId, duration, data_timestamp**

I am trying to write a query that selects userId and average session duration for each “Good User”

- Good user: a user with an average of at least 4 sessions in a week

I tried writing the following query but I am still missing lots of points

```
SELECt avg_sessions
FROM (
SELECT
    S1.userid,
    COUNT(distinct id) as num_sessions
FROM
    sessions
WHERE data_timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(data_timestamp, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY userid) as cte
```

Example:
for the following data:
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UalIt.png)

we get the following analysis:
[Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mq2D.png)

and the final result is :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5TMx.png)

Comment: which database are you using-> oracle, postgresql,sql server?

Comment: In addition to the database tag, sample data and desired results would help.  As would more clarity.  What do you mean by week?  Any 7 days?  Seven particular days?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this. I use a week_dt column to group together the dates. This is followed by selecting users who have had atleast 5 sessions during that week.

```
SELECT
     S1.userid,
     DATE_SUB(data_timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(data_timestamp) DAY) as week_dt,
     COUNT(distinct id)/7 as num_sessions
FROM
    sessions
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(distinct id)/7>=5
```

Comment: Hi George, Many thanks for your answer!! but you need to provide users who have an average of at least 5 sessions in a week and not who have a total count of 5 sessions during a week

Comment: so divide by 7 then?